# How to Convert Tuple to Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

i'm using Python 2.5 and Win XP. i have a tuple as below:

```
>>> a
(None, '{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}')
>>> a[1]
'{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}'
>>>
```

i want to convert tuple a[1] to dictionary because i want to use the key and value. pls help to advise. tq

Comment: `a` is a tuple, `a[1]` is already a dictionary. For instanche, a[1][4] would give you `8`.

Comment: a[1] is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Where is this tuple coming from?  Are the keys and values always numeric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a[1])
{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}
```

Comment: @maximus: there is no `ast` module in Python2.5. Put [ast.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/ast.py?view=markup) somewhere in your `sys.path`.

Answer (score 3):

First split the string on comma.
Iterate over all parts.
Split each part on colon.
Convert the strings into integers.
Add the second integer as value for the first integer as key.

Comment: You've also to remove the brackets before splitting

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the source of `a[1]` you can use `eval`:

```
dictionary = eval(a[1])
```

Otherwise you can use `json` (or `simplejson` in Python 2.5: [see here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/)) :

```
import json
dictionay = json.loads(a[1])
```

**Note**: it mostly depends on how you got the string: if it comes from a `repr` and cannot be hacked, `eval` may be good.
If it came from `json.dumps` (which would result in a different string), you should use `json.loads`.

Comment: This may work, but is dangerous unless you trust the contents of `a[1]` completely to always have the correct format and never contain malicious data.  `eval` can do pretty much anything given the right string, so if there is ANY chance of `a[1]` being badly or maliciously generated, DO NOT use eval on it.

Comment: don't use `eval` if `ast.literal_eval()` [works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633095/how-to-convert-tuple-to-dictionary/5633170#5633170). `a[1]` is not in JSON format.

Comment: i can't import json as it said error no module json. i'm using Python 2.5. but i can use dictionary=eval(a[1]) and it works! great.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it, without using any imports.

A simple **list comprehension** (temp):

```
>>> a
(None, '{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}')
>>> a[1]
'{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}'
>>> temp = [[int(c) for c in b.split(":")] for b in a[1].strip('{}').split(",")]
>>> a_dict = dict(temp)
>>> a_dict[1]
2
>>> a_dict[2]
4
```

Comment: You can use `a[1].strip('{}')` to remove brackets

Comment: you could use `genexpr` with the `dict` constructor: `dict(map(int, pair.split(":")) for pair in a[1].strip('{}').split(","))`

Comment: Is there any advantage of your expression over `dict([[int(c) for c in b.split(":")] for b in a[1].strip('{}').split(",")])`?

Comment: there is almost no difference in this case. `dict([...])` supports python2.3, creates one additional list, and leaks `b`, `c` names into outer scope. `dict(map...)` might be more/less readable depending on how sensitive you're to excessive punctuation or whether you're familiar with `map()`.  In short the difference is minuscule.

Answer (score 0):

> The dict() constructor builds
>   dictionaries directly from lists of
>   key-value pairs stored as tuples. When
>   the pairs form a pattern, list
>   comprehensions can compactly specify
>   the key-value list.
>
> > > dict([('sape', 4139), ('guido', 4127), ('jack', 4098)])
> > >           {'sape': 4139, 'jack': 4098, 'guido': 4127}
> > >       dict([(x, x**2) for x in (2, 4, 6)])     # use a list comprehension
> > >           {2: 4, 4: 16, 6: 36}

Copy & Paste from: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: hi,

>>> a
(None, '{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}')
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> a[1]
'{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}'
>>> type(a[1])
<type 'str'>

sorry for the confusion. seems like a[1] is a string type. how would i convert str to dict? tq

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Then you're better off with Dons json solution, provided your string-tuple "syntax" is like the one from json